# List of rss feeds to test my feed reader

Tags: xml, rss, feed, atom-feed

I'm looking for a list (the bigger the better) of rss feeds to test a feed reader I'm writing. I couldn't find anything using google. How can I go about testing my reader with a large number of feeds for a variety of sources?

Does anyone know of any list of sources that are available out there?

Thanks

Comment: You are writing a feed reader and don't have 60 of your personal reads in some other reader that you could use?

Comment: My app is a hosted script that should work well retrieving many urls. I'd like to test its limits. I'll have only a small number of users, and I think ~1000 feeds should be enough. 60 is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a feed of feeds: http://www.syndic8.com/genfeed.php?Format=rss

Answer (score 0):

There are [2 lists there](http://blog.superfeedr.com/top-feeds-list/): 40k feeds and 4k feeds. These lists are on [github too](http://github.com/superfeedr/popular-feeds).

Have you implemented PubSubHubbub in your feed reader?